# Issue is when I am not using my application for a long time, after come back and when clicking any tab its redirects to the login page using MSAL js

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, single-page-application, msal.js

> Using MSALjs SPA for refrence.
> [MSALjs Library](https://github.com/mvertopoulos/vue-msal#readme)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Issue is when I am not using my application for a long time, after come back and when clicking any tab its redirects to the login page using MSAL js. But it should not redirect to login page, should be keep login.